# FxCop metrics.exe failing with error parsing IL

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, fxcop

using MSBuild from visual studio 2015.

running metrics.exe against the compiled assemblies.

The exceptions below are being thrown.

Any suggestions on how to proceed to address the problem would be appreciated.

This started after I added an inner class 'StandardFactory' to the class 'BaseClass'

I'm assuming that the IL is somehow different with 2015.

Regards,

James

======================

```
An error was encountered while parsing IL for method: 'BaseClass`1+StandardFactory`1+<InitAsync>d__2.MoveNext', instruction at offset '0x17' with opcode 'Ldfld'.
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.ILParser.GetMemberFromToken()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstruction()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstructions()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseMethodInstructions(Method method, Int32 methodIndex, Int32 RVA)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodInstructions(Method method, Object i)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodBody(Method method, Object i, Boolean asInstructionList)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Method.get_Instructions()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.RuleUtilities.HasImperativeSecurityAction(Method method, SecurityAction action)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.RuleUtilities.HasSecurityAction(Method method, SecurityAction action)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.RuleUtilities.HasSecurityAction(Method method, SecurityAction[] actions)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.RecordCallSites(Method caller)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitMember(Member member, TargetMember target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitMembers(MemberCollection members, TargetMemberDictionary targets, Boolean visitNestedTypes)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitMembers(MemberCollection members, TargetMemberDictionary targets, Boolean visitNestedTypes)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitMembers(MemberCollection members, TargetMemberDictionary targets, Boolean visitNestedTypes)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitTypes(TypeNodeCollection types, TargetNamespaceDictionary targets)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitModule(ModuleNode module, TargetModule target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitAssembly(AssemblyNode assembly, TargetFile target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitAssembly(AssemblyNode assembly, TargetFile target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.Load(TargetFile target, Boolean buildTree, Boolean queueItems, AssemblyNode loadedAssembly)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.LoadAssemblies(Queue queue, ExceptionCollection exceptions)
Analyzing...
An error was encountered while parsing IL for method: 'BaseClass`1+StandardFactory`1.InitAsync(System.String)', instruction at offset '0x8' with opcode 'Stfld'.
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.ILParser.GetMemberFromToken()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstruction()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstructions()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseMethodInstructions(Method method, Int32 methodIndex, Int32 RVA)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodInstructions(Method method, Object i)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodBody(Method method, Object i, Boolean asInstructionList)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Method.get_Instructions()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.AnonymousMethodTable.GetAnonymousMethodsRecursivelyFromInstructions(Method declaringMethod, Set`1 results)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.MethodMetrics..ctor(Method method, Predicate`1 couplingFilter)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.TypeMetrics..ctor(TypeNode type, Predicate`1 filter, Predicate`1 couplingFilter)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.BaseMetrics.GetMetricsFor(Node node, Predicate`1 filter, Predicate`1 couplingFilter)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Rules.Maintainability.AvoidUnmaintainableCode.Check(TypeNode type)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.CheckType(TypeNode type, TargetType target)
```